# How to set one queuing discipline for two network interfaces

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

In my home I have modem/switch/router device which provides me WAN. I want to use spare notebook as second router with capability of smart queuing management (SQM) and different services. I have following setup.

```
                                    eth1  ----------- PC 
      router --- eth0 --- notebook |
                                    wifi(hotspot)---- mobile_devices
```

I want to apply one CAKE SQM with rule of bandwidth limitation for both eth1 and wifi(hotspot) in order to prevent buffer bloating on router. I know how to attach qdisc to specific interface but what I do not know is how to connect both eth1 and wifi(hotspot) to be seen as one device.

To sum up I want to achieve following scenario.

```
                                                           eth1  ----------- PC
      router --- eth0 --- notebook --- "virtual interface"|
                                                           wifi(hotspot)---- mobile_devices
```

With qdisc applied to "virtual interface"

I am using Ubuntu-server on notebook.

But if there is different way of limiting outgoing traffic with one limiting rule then I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a Raspberry Pi 4 and OpenWrt bundled with LUCI web interface.
If you have the Linux skills you can compile and build your OpenWrt image using the OpenWrt images.  Others have compiled an image where you have everything you need to run the Raspberry Pi4 as a router, using LUCI to configure and implement firewall and SQM etc.

I used this for a couple of days with ZERO impact on network speed.
I hooked up the eth0 onboard Ethernet to the LAN side so it had a static IP address, and a USB3 Ethernet converter (Allowing me 1 Gbps) eth1 to WAN using DHCP.  This replaces your notebook and is therefore in series with your router and ISP.

Here is the link to the OpenWrt project website: https://openwrt.org/

Here is a link to the most up to date OpenWrt with LUCI image that I could find at the time of this writing (2021-04-17): https://github.com/wulfy23/rpi4
And here is the git clone URL: https://github.com/wulfy23/rpi4.git

Here is a walkthrough to get your RPi4 set up: (use the image from wulfy23 instead though) https://www.instructables.com/Highspeed-VPN-Router-With-Raspberry-Pi/

I just found an awesome video describing how to compile your own version of OpenWrt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MFkbcNFIqo